# Latest Version of P4V Does Not Set Up A Resolve

Tags: perforce, p4v

I updated to the latest version of Perforce P4V (see below) and the behavior has changed.

I want to Submit a change list and must get the latest revision of a file to set up a resolve.

When I select the file from the Submit panel, right click and select the option "Get Latest Revision", perforce will just overwrite my local copy with the latest version of the file without asking me to resolve conflicts.  I want to accept the target file and not merge with the latest version.

The impact of this is that I have lost my changes so I must revert the file to it's original and manually add back all my code changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer the implied question of "how do I report a bug with P4V?"

Answer: To file a bug report with Perforce you should write to `support@perforce.com`.

Answer (score 2):

From Perforce Support:

P4V 2018.3/1706936 included this new functionality:

```
#18050 (Change #1670254)
    Added a new Server Data preference, " Automatic Safe Resolve (no
    merging) when syncing files". This preference is turned on by default.
    As a result, when syncing files (Get Latest...), P4V now runs a safe
    resolve (no merging).
```

[image]

Comment: If that is the root cause, based on OP's report it sounds like it's running `resolve -at` rather than `resolve -as`... yikes!

Comment: I will mention that to the OP

Comment: The way to check is to look at the log pane and see what `p4 resolve` command it runs when you sync.  A "safe" resolve is `resolve -as` and it **should not discard your changes**; it will leave the resolve pending if there are any differences at all between the two files.  `resolve -at` is "irrevocably overwrite whatever is in your workspace" and is the exact opposite of "safe".  If the "safe resolve" option is running a `resolve -at` it's just about the worst data loss bug a client could possibly introduce (short of, I dunno, running `p4 revert` at random intervals).

Comment: I could not reproduce the behavior by toggling the Automatic Safe Resolve setting and I did not see resolve -at.  But the problem went away once I unchecked the default setting.

Comment: I think comments have misinterpreted.  With that checkbox off, resolve is not called.  With on, 'resolve -as' is called.  This is a problem if I want to manually resolve between an older and newer version of the file, as the local file is discarded.  So uncheck the setting.